# In which context default argument of immediate function is substituted in C++20 (on source location example)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, consteval

In C++20 a new feature was added to get the source location information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Here is a slightly modified example from that page, where an addition immediate function `loc` is used to get the source location:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <source_location>
 
consteval auto loc(std::source_location x = std::source_location::current() ) { return x; }

void log(const std::string_view message,
         const std::source_location location = loc()) {
    std::cout << "file: "
              << location.file_name() << "("
              << location.line() << ":"
              << location.column() << ") `"
              << location.function_name() << "`: "
              << message << '\n';
}
 
template <typename T> void fun(T x) { log(x); }
 
int main(int, char*[]) {
    log("Hello world!");
    fun("Hello C++20!");
}
```

In the latest MSVC 2019 it prints as in the original example from cppreference.com:

```
file: main.cpp(25:5) `main`: Hello world!
file: main.cpp(20:5) `fun`: Hello C++20!
```

But in GCC the *same line* is indicated twice in the output:

```
file: /app/example.cpp(8:51) ``: Hello world!
file: /app/example.cpp(8:51) ``: Hello C++20!
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nqE4cr9d4

Which of the compilers is right here?

And if define `loc` function not as immediate one:

```
auto loc(std::source_location x = std::source_location::current() ) { return x; }
```

then the output of GCC changes and resembles the original example:

```
file: /app/example.cpp(20:8) `int main(int, char**)`: Hello world!
file: /app/example.cpp(17:42) `void fun(T) [with T = const char*]`: Hello C++20!
```

While MSVC refuses to compile it with the error:

```
error C7595: 'std::source_location::current': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vorW4f9ax

Please also suggest, which compiler is right in not-immediate case as well?

Comment: It is **undefined behavior** unless the standard says how it should behave in such cases. You make the code harder to read to anyone who don't know what `loc` does. Declare `log` function as intended using `std::source_location::current()` as the default value.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in [17.8.2.1.2 `[support.srcloc.class]`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf#page=525&zoom=100,85,216) (emphasis mine):

> *Remarks*: Any call to `current` that appears as a default member initializer (11.4), or as a subexpression
> thereof, should correspond to the location of the constructor definition or aggregate initialization that
> uses the default member initializer. **Any call to `current` that appears as a default argument (9.3.3.6),
> or as a subexpression thereof, should correspond to the location of the invocation of the function that
> uses the default argument (7.6.1.2)**.

From this, I deduce that GCC is right.

When the call to `current` happens in line 5, it returns a `source_location` object that *"correspond[s] to the location of the invocation of the function **(in this case the function `loc`)**  that
uses the default argument"*.

In this case the invocation location is `8:51` (the expression `const std::source_location location = loc()`).

Why the function name is empty is explained by the following:

1. 17.8.2.1.1.1 (Table 38) tells us that the function name should be "such as in" `__func__`.

> | Element | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | `function_name_` | A name of the current function such as in `__func__` (9.5.1) if any, an empty string otherwise. |

2. 9.5.1.8 Example shows that if `__func__` appears as a default argument, the name is undefined. I know that examples are nonnormative text, but this clearly describes the intent:

> [Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
> S() : s(__func__) { } // OK
> const char* s;
> };
> void f(const char* s = __func__); // error: __func__ is undeclared
> ```
>
> — end example]

Comment: [dcl.fct.def.general]/7 explains (normatively) that `__func__` is usable only in the *function-body*; this way the function type is known should the implementation want to include it in the name.

Comment: This doesn’t address the non-`consteval` `loc` case (which I don’t think *should* change anything).

Comment: @DavisHerring I know it doesn't address the second issue, but I wanted to at least help with the first question, as I wasn't able to find an answer for the second one yet. I thought that maybe the issue in `g++` was caused by inlining and MSVC had a bug. However, no matter what I did - marking the function as `noinline` or using `-O0` - nothing changed.

Comment: I believe the quoted remark relates to default initialization of class members and not to default values of a function argument. But good idea, let us consider this example as well. Here GCC prints the third distinct result, pointing now to function `log`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GsW1586n1

Comment: @Fedor The excerpt from 17.8.2.1.2 `[support.srcloc.class]` refers to both in-class initialization and default function arguments. The emphasized part says that it refers to "Any call to `current` that **appears as a default argument (9.3.3.6)**, or as a subexpression thereof". The referenced section 9.3.3.6 is `[dcl.fct.default]`, which should dispel any ambiguity whether the excerpt applies to the situation in question.

Comment: The described behavior in the question was with GCC 12, while it was changed in GCC 13, which now resembles MSVC 2019: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tazfd8K4M